# How to fix Directory import '@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server' is not supported resolving ES modules after updating Angular to version 13

Tags: node.js, angular, exception, angular13

When running `ng serve` I get the following error after updating my angular version:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Directory import 'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\desktop-server-client-app\desktop\server\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server' is not supported 
resolving ES modules imported from C:\Users\xxx\Documents\desktop-server-client-app\desktop\server\client\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
Did you mean to import C:/Users/xxx/Documents/desktop-server-client-app/desktop/server/client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server/index.js?
See "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-TMJqg5\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Log output:

```
[error] Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import 'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\desktop-server-client-app\desktop\server\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from C:\Users\xxx\Documents\desktop-server-client-app\desktop\server\client\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
    Did you mean to import C:/Users/xxx/Documents/desktop-server-client-app/desktop/server/client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server/index.js?
        at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:272:17)
        at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:699:10)
        at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:810:11)
        at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:85:40)
        at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:229:28)
        at Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:164:28)
        at importModuleDynamically (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1006:27)
        at exports.importModuleDynamicallyCallback (internal/process/esm_loader.js:30:14)
        at eval (eval at loadEsmModule (C:\Users\xxx\Documents\desktop-server-client-app\desktop\server\client\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:195:12), <anonymous>:3:1)
        at loadEsmModule (C:\Users\xxx\Documents\desktop-server-client-app\desktop\server\client\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:195:68)
```

Could somebody explain to me what this error means and how I could fix it? It seems to me that this is some kind of compatibility problem I can't do much about. My angular project so far just contains some boilerplate code, so it shouldn't be the problem.

Edit: My versions are the following:

```
Node: 14.15.0
npm: 6.14.8
Angular: 13.2.4

@angular-devkit/architect: 0.1202.16
@angular-devkit/build-angular: 12.2.16
@angular-devkit/core: 12.2.16
@angular-devkit/schematics: 13.2.5
@angular/cdk: 12.2.13
@angular/cli: 13.2.5
@angular/material: 12.2.13
@schematics/angular: 13.2.5
rxjs: 6.6.7
typescript: 4.5.5
```

Comment: Which node version do you have?

Comment: Node: v14.15.0
npm: v6.14.8

Comment: I would recommend you make all of the packages on the same version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I faced this problem because I updated my project to Angular 13 using `--legacy-peer-deps` flag. Because of that, there were old dependencies still present in `package.json`.

Make sure you have the appropriate package version regarding the thrown error. In your precise case, try to change

`"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.16"`
to `"@angular-devkit/build-angular":  "~13.2.5"`

then run `npm install`.

Comment: I upgraded from Angular 12 but your solution solved my problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: to add more to this, I was able to bypass the error by manually updating the "@angular-devkit/build-angular" to 16.2.8 for Angular 16